# How can I use a keyword in git book in a string?

Tags: gitbook

Im documenting some code and it includes a | operator, but since the pipe charatcer is used for filters im getting this error

“Error:filter not found: quote”

The line itself is “ [somecode] | quote “

This code is being displayed in a table. I’ve tried tags `<code>` and `’’’`but it’s not working. it still thinks i’m using an undefined filter, how can i fix this?